# Ensuring commutavity / reciprocity in dictionary of county boundaries

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

**BACKGROUND**: I'm starting with the US Census's County Adjacency File. Unfortunately, the file is inconsistently formatted such that my initial script to extract this `tab` delimited file into a dictionary with key of county `i` (denoted by its Fips code) and values of a list of all counties adjacent to county `i` (again using Fips codes) produces errors.

**PROBLEM**: My current dictionary violates "reciprocity". If one county borders another county, the second county must also border the first. In my dictionary, for county `i`, there is often a county `j` that is in county `i`'s values of adjacent counties, but county `i` is not contained in the values of key county `j`.

**DESIRED SOLUTION**: A dictionary or list of lists containing an entry for each county (key or `0`th entry) and all its adjacent counties.

**TASK**: Iterating through each item in a dictionary, visiting all items with a key in the list of values of each item, and checking whether the reciprocal relationship holds  (and if not, adding that key)

Minimum Working Example (nonsense values):

```
Adj_counties_pre  = { 12000 : [12001, 12003], 
                      12001 : [12004], 
                      12003 : [12004, 12001], 
                      12004 : [12003, 12000]}
...
Adj_counties_post = { 12000 : [12001, 12003, 12004], 
                      12001 : [12004, 12003, 12000], 
                      12003 : [12004, 12001, 12000], 
                      12004 : [12003, 12000, 12001]}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to traverse the dictionary to fix this.
 Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Furthermore shouldn't `12000` be a member of `12001`?

Comment: Not homework. And yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use the following solution:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)

for k,vs in adj_counties_pre.items():
    for v in vs:
        result[k].add(v)
        result[v].add(k)

adj_counties_post = {k:list(v) for k,v in result.items()}
```

The code works as follows, first we construct a temporary `defaultdict(set)`. A `defaultdict` is a dictionary that constructs a value by invoking the *factory* (here `set`) if it cannot find a certain key.

Next we iterate over all key-value pairs `(k,vs)`. And for every value `vs` over its elements `v`. For each key-element pair, we add the element `v` to the set associated with the key `k`, and the key `k` to the set associated with the element `v`.

Next we either are done (a `defaultdict` is a dictionary and this one maps county codes on a *set of county codes*), or we can decide to turn it into a *vanilla dictionary* with the dictionary comprehension. This then generates:

```
>>> adj_counties_post
{12000: [12001, 12003, 12004], 12001: [12000, 12003, 12004], 12003: [12000, 12001, 12004], 12004: [12000, 12001, 12003]}
```

also note that variables usually start with a lowercase.